# I am trying to find the average of a COUNT request

Tags: postgresql, subquery, aggregate

I have completed the query below from an invoices table which gives me the total invoices attached to each house ID. So house_id 114 has 14 invoices attached to it. Is there a way to feed this result into a query to find the average number of invoices attached to each house.

```
SELECT h_id AS house_id, 
COUNT (h_id) AS total_invoices  
FROM maintenance GROUP BY house_id 
ORDER BY total_invoices 
DESC
```

```
house_id      total_invoices
114               14
116               11
46                10
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404141/how-to-do-a-select-in-another-select-with-postgresql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a sub-select query you can apply the `AVG` function on top of your `COUNT` query to get the single average like so:

```
SELECT AVG(InvoiceCounts.total_invoices)
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT (h_id) AS total_invoices  
    FROM maintenance GROUP BY house_id 
) InvoiceCounts
```

Another method:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(h_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT h_id) AS average_invoices_per_house
FROM maintenance;
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the neat things with SQL is that it is closed under relational operators. I.e the result of a query is a derived table that you can query again. So you just apply avg to the result of your count query.

In addition, you can get both the counts and the average in a single query by using grouping sets. I'm using group by cube, since there is only one column involved:

```
select house_id, avg(cnt)
from (
    select house_id, count(1) as cnt
    from maintenance
    group by house_id
) as t
group by cube (house_id)

house_id    avg
    11.6666666666666667
116 11.0000000000000000
114 14.0000000000000000
46  10.0000000000000000
```

The row with house_id null is the total average. Instead of `group by cube (house_id)`, `group by grouping sets ( (house_id), () )` could have been used.

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=48f47f748db62f51007403d7a7d75913)

Answer (score -1):

Use AVG instead of COUNT

```
SELECT h_id AS house_id, 
AVG (h_id) AS total_invoices  
FROM maintenance GROUP BY house_id 
ORDER BY total_invoices 
DESC
```

Comment: I am looking for a single result. Perhaps it should say average number of invoices per house. So in the table above the result I'm looking for is (14+11+10)/3